# ASP.NET HttpModule: prevent chunked Transfer-Encoding

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, httpmodule, chunked-encoding

I'm working on an HttpModule that does its own HTTP (gzip) compression. The problem is that as soon as I set the `Content-Encoding` response header to any "compressable" value (like `gzip`, `deflate` etc.) and return the compressed response in the stream, IIS switches the `Transfer-Encoding` to `chunked` and the response doesn't really get compressed (tested in both Chrome and IE dev tools).

I'm also explicitly setting the `Content-Length` to the length of the compressed byte array, but it doesn't show up in the actual HTTP response on the client.

If I set `Transfer-Encoding` to `identity` or do not specify it at all and push the uncompressed bytes to the output stream, the response is sent normally, without chunking.

I have reduced the HttpModule to below example. It logs the `Compressed 123 bytes to 110` message, but Chrome records the actual response to be 271 bytes.

How do I prevent this behavior? I tried explicitly setting the `Content-Length` in `HttpContext.Current.Response` (read somewhere it can help), but it does not help either.

```
public class SimpleTestHttpModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Init (HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.BeginRequest += Application_BeginRequest;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }

    private static void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpApplication application = (HttpApplication)sender;
        HttpContext httpContext = application.Context;

        string text = @"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.";
        byte[] uncompressedBytes = new UTF8Encoding (false).GetBytes (text);

        httpContext.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";

        GZipCompressAndWrite(httpContext, uncompressedBytes);

        httpContext.Response.End();
    }

    private static void GZipCompressAndWrite (HttpContext context, byte[] bytes)
    {
        context.Response.AddHeader ("Content-Encoding", "gzip");

        byte[] compressed = GZipCompressByteArray (bytes);
        log.DebugFormat ("Compressed {0} bytes to {1}", bytes.Length, compressed.Length);

        string contentLenStr = compressed.Length.ToString (CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers["Content-Length"] = contentLenStr;
        context.Response.Headers["Content-Length"] = contentLenStr;
        context.Response.BinaryWrite (compressed);
    }

    private static byte[] GZipCompressByteArray (byte[] data)
    {
        using (MemoryStream outputStream = new MemoryStream ())
        {
            using (GZipStream compressStream = new GZipStream(outputStream, CompressionMode.Compress, false))
                compressStream.Write (data, 0, data.Length);

            outputStream.Flush();
            return outputStream.ToArray ();
        }
    }

    private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
}
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?  I'm seeing something similar/same.

Comment: @TomK unfortunately no, I eventually gave up on it :(